How can I create a Word (macOS) style for a script to insert a speaker's initial on the first line and indent their remaining speech?
I want to create a style for each speaker in a script/transcript so that, when their style is selected, Word automatically inserts their initial at the first line of their section's  first paragraph and indents the remaining text until the next speaker's style is applied, like so:

Creating a style for the indentation seems straightforward enough, but I'm having difficulty with how to automatically insert the speaker's initial at the start of the first paragraph.
I tried using a customised multi-level list with a speaker's initial as the first-level character, but it doesn't work as intended where a speaker's section might have multiple paragraphs, as it inserts the specified character at the start of each character (and it might mess the formatting of any further tabbed text in a paragraph?).

If I understand correctly, your screencap show what the end result should be. What does the initial document look like?

A style cannot contain a letter or text. AutoText can. Autotext can be triggered by a keyboard shortcut or AutoComplete. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm#AutoComplete

If you are in a position to use some VBA (or perhaps even AppleScript) you could do this by creating code that let you select a person/set of styles, applied the initials+indent style to the selected paragraph, inserted the appropriate initials, then applied the "unindented" style to every subsequent paragraph until you reached an indented paragraph with a style associated with another person. That kind of thing.

@cybernetic.nomad - there isn't an initial document; I was trying to set up the document so the respective style could be selected and the script/dialogue then typed. That said, based on Charles Kenyon's reply, it appears I can't use a style to format a script as desired anyway.

Based on @Charles Kenyon's reply to my question, it appears styles cannot be created or applied in the way that I am wanting to. AutoText may be more suitable, as he suggests, or as @jonsson suggests, VBA might achieve it.
